# Can't respond to Interaction after using interaction.response.defer() [Nextcord]

Tags: discord, nextcord

I have a slash command, but it requires few seconds for processing. Since Discord limitation for responding to interactions seems to be 3s, i found on the documentation the [interaction.response.defer()](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.InteractionResponse.defer) method, that should tell Discord that i've recieved the command (not to throw the error "Interaction didn't responded.")

```py
@client.slash_command(description="Test command", guild_ids=[123456789123456789])
async def test(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # Doing stuff
    await interaction.response.send_message("My actual content")
```

But I get this error :

```
nextcord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`interaction.followup.send()`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Interaction.followup) should be used instead of `send_message()`